# How to explain DataType Range by owl?

Tags: owl, ontology

I want to explain "light weight car is under 300kg" in OWL using `minCardinality` or `maxCardinality`

Is it possible?

Comment: "explan" is **not** an English word, so unclear what you're asking here ...

Comment: and using min or maxCardinality doesn't make sense when we assume (what obviously only makes sense) to have a data property `hasWeight`. You have to use OWL 2 facets. `Class: LightWeightCar SubClassOf: (Car and hasWeight some int[<= 300])`